# Sound notification settings, each room a different config

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, audio

> **Mods:** I believe the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) you linked is the one duplicated. This suggestion was made 1 year ago, whereas the one that you may think it's older, has been made just 4 days ago.

Say for example I have 3 rooms opened as pinned tabs in my chrome (or browser).

I find the first room interesting and there's few people in there, so I set "Sound notifications: visible room".

Since changes in sound notifications are applied to all rooms at once, the problem comes when the other two rooms start spamming the sound (lots of people) as new messages are coming, and whenever I switch tab to them, sometimes they come up with something interesting or worth talking about... and sometimes not.

But what if I want to make this setting work for one specific room, and then the ones that I don't care at all I'd like to make them sound only when I'm mentioned or totally mute them.

Comment: And your question is you'd like sound settings per room?

Comment: @JonH This is a feature request, therefore, question would be if you agree  or disagree with the idea.

Comment: Re: edit -- dupes often do favor older questions, but are more likely to favor those with stronger support or better answers, as the case may be.